# Paginate method is not found on ActiveRecord::Relation with MetaSearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, meta-search

I'm trying to paginate my search results from metasearch but I get a

```
undefined method `paginate' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x6d3df28>
```

This is the code in my controller :

```
@search = Camping.search(params[:search])

if !params[:search].nil?
  @campings = @search.paginate(:page => params[:page])
else
  @campings = [];
end
```

This should be so simple I really don't see what's wrong...

I have those in my gem file :

```
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'
```

Comment: Could you provide the code of Camping.search method as well?

Comment: Obligatory dumb questions: did you run bundle install and restart the app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So yes this was dumb, just forgot to restart the server after installing the gem

Comment: I just had to login to upvote this even though this is old. Just spent like 2 hours on this. I will now proceed to virtually kick myself.